# Consuming external Restful Web API with ASP Dot net MVC

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest

I'm doing a simple page to upload document. However after I get the input I need to call a web API to get a token which will then allow me to call another web API which will finally proceed to upload the file (using the file AND the token). So what I want to know is how to call this API and retrieve it's response and then add that response (which would be the token).
I am trying following code it works fine in console application but not work on web Application.
here is my code

```
public void GetTokenpost()
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    string url = "mydomain/api/oauth/token";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";

    string data = "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=here jwt token"; // make sure this is URL encoded
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
       streamWriter.Write(data);
       streamWriter.Flush();
       streamWriter.Close();
       var HttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
       using (var streamRead = new StreamReader(HttpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
         {
            var value1 = streamRead.ReadToEnd();       
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", 
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())  
          {  
              client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://domain");  

              //Called Member default GET All records  
              //GetAsync to send a GET request   
              // PutAsync to send a PUT request  
              var responseTask = client.GetAsync(string requestUri);  
              responseTask.Wait();  

              //To store result of web api response.   
              var result = responseTask.Result;  

              //If success received   
              if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)  
              { 
               //your code for performing action
              }
```

Comment: Hi Omkar its post method .

Comment: This is will helpful- https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-post-method-in-aspnet-mvc